# speed up performance of Eigen library in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, optimization, eigen3

what and where are the settings that I should change to enhance the performance of Eigen library in visual studio 2010? In other words, in gcc, there is an option to turn the optimization on `-O3`, how can I turn on the optimization in visual studio (if that possible)?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project's property pages, select `Configuration Properties --> C/C++  --> Optimization`

[image]

Comment: it gives me this error `Command line error D8016: '/ZI and /'O1' command-line options are incompatible`